# Generic type is type script

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

```
function identity<String>(arg: String): String {
  return arg;
}
 
let myIdentity = identity([2]);
console.log()
```

Hi could someone help me to understand why this doesn't throw any type error even if i am passing a array of numbers ?

1. Is it because the type is "String" instead of "string" , which looks for objects than primitive ?
2. If answer is "yes" , if i change everything to string i get error saying string is never used

```
function identity<string>(arg: string): string {
  return arg;
}
 
let myIdentity = identity([2]);
console.log(myIdentity )

'string' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the builtin types `String` and `string` by using their names as your generic parameter. Just use a parameter name that is not a built-in to solve it:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFUTQA8oMUBnRCqAJxjAHMA+ACgDcBDAGxDQC5E+AJSDCAbwCwAKESJaaKCFpIuvNAG4ZAXxmIZqDFmysA2gCYAusI2IA9HaK1acWoguXEKOGgpgA5FBEpOTUdAyMBuiYMDis-ub+NvaOcADWQA)

```ts
function identity<T extends string>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
 
identity([2]); // error [2] doesn't extend string
identity('2'); // ok
```

If you want a generic identity function without any kind of constraint, you can use an unconstrained type parameter:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=8&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPAPAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkXwEp79EBvAWAChFEAnNFBB8kFamgDc3AL7dE3CAgDOURGBABbAEZo+AQT59y2AGpUaiALzJ0mGDmIBtAEwBdRhMQB6L2s06+R1cFZVU4LQArNGgzcSsbDCxsYjYtemdpD29fNkQ0v21dT1kuRTAVRBU+GDAAcwAZe10qWItrVET7ZIByZ26sn0QAImchkPLVdUK+Rqhmyla0eI67B2cB32duIA)

```ts
function identity<T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
 
const numberArrayValue = identity([2]); // number[]
const objectValue = identity({b: 2}); // { b: number; }
const stringLiteralValue = identity('2'); // "2"
const numberLiteralValue = identity(2); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you , so what would this statement means ? 

function identity<T extends string>(value: number): number {
  return value;
}

Comment: it doesn't throws any error even if i define generic type as T extend string , but sets param and return to number . What does this decalration logically means

Comment: @PDHide "_if i define generic type as T extend string , but sets param and return to number_": Type parameters work similarly to normal function parameters: if you don't use them, they aren't relevant. `T extends string` means that whatever value is supplied to the variable of type `T` must be assignable to the `string` type. I suggest reading the [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) section of the TypeScript handbook to learn about generic parameters and the `extends` keyword.